# "gv" stubborn complaints

Tags: ghostscript

I use "gv" command in my scripts to view ***.pdf or ***.ps files (I do that instead of using "acroread" or "okular" because "gv" has a nice option "-watch" that allows me to see changes in a  troff or LaTex file I am working on while using "vi" editor.) However in my new laptop (Dell-Precision-M with ubuntu 14-04 installed) "gv" keeps giving me trouble by always complaining like that:

$gv  test.pdf

Warning: Cannot convert string "-*-Helvetica-Medium-R-Normal--*-140-*-*-P-*-ISO8859-1" to type FontStruct

Warning: Cannot convert string "-*-Helvetica-Medium-R-Normal--*-120-*-*-P-*-ISO8859-1" to type FontStruct

Warning: Cannot convert string "-*-Helvetica-Medium-R-Normal--*-100-*-*-P-*-ISO8859-1" to type FontStruct

Warning: Cannot convert string "-*-Helvetica-Bold-R-Normal--*-120-*-*-P-*-ISO8859-1" to type FontStruct

Frankly, I don't care about those fonts, and anyway, I think it is some kind of a bug (since neither acroread nor okular ever complained about that).  So, I tried to simply suppress that warning mgs, by using any options available for "gv" command to be quiet, silent, etc, which could be found in "man gv" or "gv --help", like "-quiet", "-infoSilent", "-dsc", "-eof",  -- but to no avail. The "gv" is hell-bent on screaming out those four lines no matter what is a target file.  I could've live with that, but in my scrips a few lines after "gv" command I have a "vi" command and those complaints mess up my text in "vi".

Any way of fixing that?

Comment: You mean, aside from installing the fonts?

Comment: That is right -- aside from installing the fonts...

Comment: evince and okular also watch the file for changes and automatically reload it.

Comment: @Gilles: this is interesting info. But I looked into the okular list of options and haven't seen anything like that. There is one, "--unique                  "Unique instance" control" with unclear to me function; is it the one you are talking about? If not, anything else?

Comment: @AlKap There's no command line option. I think both evince and okular have this option in their settings, but in both cases it's on by default.

Comment: Hmm... will try and see how it works... Although my scripts with "gv" work just fine; but I'll try okular anyway a bit later...

Comment: @Gilles: I guess I am not good in implementing that; do you think you can provide some simple script that starts from the text (groff) file say "test.groff", "vi" it,  generate "test. pdf" and do "okular test.file" within the same script?

Comment: @Gilles: thanks for the idea! I made the script for using OKULAR while editing my files by "vi", transferring them into PDF either via "groff" or LaTex (actually two small scripts -- one calling another), and it works fine.  OKULAR has an additional advantage of having an easy switch for inverting colors (I like black background -- make it easier on my eyes...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would fix it by installing the fonts.  On my Debian system, those are in the `xfonts-75dpi` and `xfonts-100dpi` packages.  Red Hat uses different package names.

Other people simply ignore warnings, which are usually sent to the standard error:

```
gv test.pdf 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: thanks, but I'd rather prefer to simply quiet down my gv. I have no problems to live without those fonts.

Comment: " 2>/dev/null"; wow! that simple! It worked; thanks!!!

Comment: no problem (if it works, you can mark it accepted)